# How to install PyQt4 in 2024 on Ubuntu (to run an old project)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, python-3.4

In 2016/2017, when PyQt4 was still supported, I [made a project](https://github.com/Hamza5/TALN-Quran/) based on **Python 3** (not sure about the exact version, maybe 3.4), **PyQt4**, **Numpy**, and **Matplotlib** (Unfortunately I didn't even include a `requirements.txt` file at that time).

I want to run this code again on my Ubuntu system (Kubuntu 22.04, to be specific), but I cannot figure out how to run PyQt4 apps nowadays. PyQt4 is no longer installable through `pip` in Python 3.10 that I have on my system.

I tried to look for [random Docker images that includes PyQt4](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=pyqt4), but no success, as they are mostly designed for Python 2 and not 3, and I do not really know how to run a GUI app from a Docker container.

I tried to convert my project [into PyQt5 using a tool](https://github.com/rferrazz/pyqt4topyqt5), but it introduced a lot of errors and I have no time to debug them all, especially that most of them happened in the code that was generated from the `.ui` files. So, I need to run the project as-is.

If you have any ideas on how to run my project, so I can at least take some screenshots of it, please let me know.

Comment: Have a look at [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) in order to install multiple Python versions.

Comment: Well, you could try to build both Qt4 and PyQt4 on your own, but there's no guarantee that you will succeed, nor that it will work properly even assuming that you are able to compile them. Since most of your issues come from the pyuic generated files, if you still have the ui files you can reconvert them with the Qt5 version, which will make porting slightly simpler. If you only want to take screenshots of that program, you could try to find an old distro that includes PyQt4 and run it in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the project to PyQt5 seems by far the easiest option:

Firstly, download a fresh copy of the source and `cd` into the top directory:

```
$ cd TALN-Quran-master
```

Create a build directory:

```
$ mkdir -p build/GUI
```

Regenerate the ui modules:

```
$ for x in GUI/*.ui; do pyuic5 -o "build/${x%.ui}.py" "$x"; done
```

Download the [zip file for the qt4toqt5 tool](https://codeload.github.com/mottosso/qt4toqt5/zip/refs/heads/master) and extract it. (Do not use *pyqt4topyqt5*, as it produces broken ouptput). Then convert the python modules:

```
$ ../qt4toqt5-master/pyqt4topyqt5.py -o build/TALN-Quran-projet.py TALN-Quran-projet.py
$ ../qt4toqt5-master/pyqt4topyqt5.py -o build/Functions Functions
```

Finally, fix the matplotlib import:

```
$ sed -i 's/backend_qt4agg/backend_qt5agg/g' build/Functions/custommpl.py
```

On my arch-linux system, this does at least run without any obvious PyQt-related errors:

[image: screenshot]

However, after clicking the "Start" button, a progress-bar appears that shows some kind of corpus is being loaded - but once that finishes, a message-box is shown which complains about an invalid "ahkaam" file. Obviously, I have no idea what this means since I don't know what the format of that file is nor what the application is supposed to do - it doesn't seem to be a programming-related issue though, so presumably you can deal with that problem yourself.